# DCT of an image in octave

Tags: octave

Acording to Octave [documentation for dct2](http://octave.sourceforge.net/signal/function/dct2.html),  `dct2 (x)` Computes the 2-D discrete cosine transform of matrix `x` but when I have tried this following code I am getting an error, what can I possibly doing wrong?

```
A= imread('img.jpg')
[m,n]=size(A)
B=dct2(A)
```

it returns an error that:

```
ERROR: 'dct2' undefined near line 4 column 3
```

I have tried checking whether `A` is a matrix or not, and its a matrix, so where is the bug? I am using OCtave 3.2.4 on windows.

Comment: can you specify what OS and octave version you are using? And how you installed Octave? Installation of Octave packages may differ.

Comment: I am using Octave 3.2.4! :S

Comment: you didn't specify the (OS) operating system. Anyway, you will have to upgrade Octave because the signal package requires at least 3.6.0.

Comment: upgrade! There's more than one option to install it in Windows. You can choose between MinGW and MSVS. See [Octave's wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Windows) for instructions and download links.

Answer (score 5):

Octave is not finding the function definition. You must first install the signal package, you can download it from http://octave.sourceforge.net/signal/index.html and, in the same folder of the file, prompt octave and call:

```
pkg install signal-1.2.0.tar.gz
```

Or, as suggested by @carandraug in the comments, since Octave 3.4 you can download and install packages automatically by typing:

```
pkg install -forge signal
```

On permission errors try prompting with `sudo octave` and after installed add:

```
pkg load signal
```

before the use of `dct2` function.

Comment: There is no need to actually download the signal package. He can use the `pkg install -forge signal` command instead. Also, don't forget to load the package (they are not automatically loaded anymore)

Comment: I am using Octave 3.2.4! and it does not satisfy the dependencies! :(

Comment: In my version it says -forge does not exist :(

Comment: @sadaf2605 yes, you can upgrade octave to a version >= 3.6 to satisfy the 'signal' package dependencies, or choose a prior version of the package, available here http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Forge%20Packages/Individual%20Package%20Releases/ . It happens that the later version compatible with Octave 3.2.4 is signal-1.1.0.Hope it helps!

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thanks! FWIW, I also had to install the `control` package on my particular Octave installation (as well as `sudo apt install liboctave-dev` first from my CLI)  in order for `signal` to install... just in case anyone else is running into this issue.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `error: the following dependencies were unsatisfied:
   signal needs control >= 2.4`